# ProgressBar setValue not working libgdx

Tags: libgdx, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar for my game. Using the code below I expect the loading picture to be halfway through the background. But the result is this. I also need some padding that I don't know how to do.

[image]

```
    ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle style = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle();
    style.background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("loadingFrame.png")));
    style.background.setMinHeight((float) (HEIGHT*0.1));
    style.knob = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("loading.png")));
    style.knob.setMinHeight((float) (HEIGHT * 0.06));
    style.knobBefore = style.knob;
    //style.knob.setMinWidth((float) (WIDTH * 0.6));

    bar = new ProgressBar(0, 100, 1, false, style);
    bar.setAnimateDuration(1);
    bar.setValue(50);

    bar.setBounds(cam.position.x - (float) (WIDTH * 0.3), (float) (cam.position.y + HEIGHT * 0.38), (float) (WIDTH * 0.6), (float) (HEIGHT * 0.1));
```

Comment: Out of my head your code looks good. What if you remove the Animation Duration? Are you adding this bar to the stage and calling `.act()` on it? Are you resetting the value somewhere?

Comment: removing the animate duration fixed it indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Then I think it is not updating correctly.  Never used animate on a ProgressBar, are you calling act each frame so that animation will update too?

Comment: Currently not, I will add it up.

Comment: It's fine now. Thanks.